# Word order when combining sentences into a Kausalsatz

Tags: word-order, conjunction

> Wir bleiben zu Hause. Heute regnet es.

Combining with weil:

> Wir bleiben zu Hause, weil es heute regnet.

By what rule did the original order of heute-> es become es-> heute? I understand that the verb is at the end after conjunctions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

German word order is more flexible in main clauses than in subordinate clauses. In a main clause, either the subject *es* or the adverb *heute* can come first. It the first example you happened to use the adverb, but it could just as easily have been *Es regnet heute.* German prefers subject first in a subordinate clause, so the normal phrasing would be *... weil es heute regnet.* But as far as I know, it's still a preference rather than a "rule".

Comment: so, heute es regnet in the second sentence highlighted sentence is also right?

Comment: @User688539: I believe so, yes. It would put a lot of stress on *heute* though. Perhaps *Gestern gingen wir spazieren. Aber weil heute es regnet, wir bleiben zu Hause.*

Comment: No, "weil heute es regnet" is not correct German. Also in the second sentence you'll have to change the word order to put the verb in front of the subject. So the correct sentence would be: "Aber weil es heute regnet, bleiben wir zuhause."

Comment: @Tilman Schmidt: You're right on the second point, a rookie mistake on my part. I'm not sure on the first point. For example I found *Weil heute nichts im Fernsehen kommt.* in the DWDS usage database. This has adverb first rather than the subject *nichts*. There do seem to be at least some cases where the subject does not have to come first in a subordinate clause.

Comment: "..., weil heute es regnet" is indeed incorrect. The reason is that the pronoun *es* must be near to the beginning of the sentence. In "Heute regnet es" *es* is in position 3 because *Heute* is first and the verb must follow. But "Heute regnet den ganzen Tag es" would be inorrect.

Comment: @RHa: I understand that a pronoun is rarely put at the end of a clause, and the subject nearly always comes near the beginning. You certainly have a better ear for what "sounds" wrong in German, but I still don't understand the reason *es* must come first in a subclause. Why is *weil heute nichts ...* correct but *weil heute es ...* incorrect?